# what does ERESTARTNOINTR in strace lsof output mean?

Tags: linux, rhel5

I have an output  as shown below, I need to understand the meaning of the error ERESTARTNOINTR and reason behind it.

```
  munmap(0x2ac7d7b3a000, 4096)            = 0
  close(4)                                = 0
  close(5)                                = 0
  **rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x411020, [ALRM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2ac7d7f82030}, {0x45, [TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 PIPE ALRM CONT TSTP TTOU XFSZ], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_NODEFER|0x1674a10, 0x23}, 8) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)**

 --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x411020, [ALRM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2ac7d7f82030}, {SIG_DFL, [ALRM], 
 SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2ac7d7f82030}, 8) = 0
 alarm(5)                                = 0
 wait4(-1, NULL, 0, NULL)                = 22301
 alarm(0)                                = 5
 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [ALRM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2ac7d7f82030}, {0x411020, [ALRM], 
 SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2ac7d7f82030}, 8) = 0
```

I facing a problem where access to a particular directory in a storage  is fast from one server while slow from other. And when there is a delay in access I am trying to run lsof output on that directory and getting this output.

thanks